# HtmlAnchor control not opening in new window

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have the following code to dynamically create an `HtmlAnchor` and assign its `HRef` property. When I right click the link and do "save target as" it is downloading the pdf, but when clicking the link is not opening in a new tab.

```
 HtmlAnchor htmlanc = new HtmlAnchor();
 htmlanc.HRef = "file:\\arts\Shared\Let";
 htmlanc.Title = "Letter Link"; 
 htmlanc.InnerText = "file:\\arts\Shared\Let";
 htmlanc.Target = "_blank";                               
 pnlLet.Controls.Add(htmlanc);
```

when i click on the link it is generation an error which in the below image.[image]

And the path is in a network folder which is shared. Is the error generating because my application cannot access the path. I checked with the networking guys but they say that the application have full access to the network shared folder, but i doubt it.

Comment: What is the generated output on the page? Does it include `target="_blank"`?

Comment: it will open a pdf file in a new tab.

Comment: the `target="_blank"` determines whether the link is opened in a new tab when left clicked.  I am curious if this is rendered in the output.

Comment: What @Kami is saying is when you **right-click** on the web page and **View source** what do you see inside the `<a href ... />` element. Is the `target="..."` correctly set to `_blank`?

Comment: nothing is happening when left clicked. when i right click and choose open in new window also it is not opening. But when i do "save target as" by right clicking it is downloading the pdf file. and yes target is set to _blank

Comment: @Nair, we understand when you click on the LINK but we are asking for the source that is GENERATED and makes the page you see on the screen. If you are using Chrome press **Ctrl + U** and then you will see the generated code. Look your you `<a href...` attribute and paste it along with all the attributes so we can see what is actually making the page. EVEN BETTER - Right-click on your link and select `Inspect Element` to see what is is made up of (`a href`) and what else!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this to be a comment but it seems you are struggling to understand our help so I wanted to expand it here.

I have copied your code sample and put on `Page_Load` of a blank WebForms solution.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var htmlanc = new HtmlAnchor();
    htmlanc.HRef = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281667/htmlanchor-control-not-opening-in-new-window";
    htmlanc.Title = "Open Question";
    htmlanc.InnerText = "Open Question";
    htmlanc.Target = "_blank";
    Controls.Add(htmlanc);
}
```

When running it you can right-click on the link:
[image: Right-Click on link]

Then you can see all of the attributes and see the `target="_blank"`:
[image: Element information]

When I click this link it correctly shows in a new tab. If you follow the above steps can you check your link has the correct `target` set and expand on what happens when you click it? Depending on your browser it may be set to download based on mime-type rather than opening a new tab etc.